# Call to a member function roles() on null in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting started on mastering Laravel. I'm trying to create a system where the superuser can edit the roles of all the users. It has been going well until now.

My front end looks like this:

```
@section('content')
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Admin</th>
        <th>Superuser</th>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
               <form action="{{ route('superuser.assign') }}" method="post">
                   <td>{{$user->first_name}}</td>
                   <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                   <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_user"></td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_admin"></td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Superuser') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_superuser"></td>

                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                   <td><button type="submit">Assign Roles</button></td>
               </form>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
@endsection
```

The problem is that when I try to assign a role to an existing user through my front end, it throws the error
`Call to a member function roles() on null`

I have a UserController that looks like this:

```php
    public function postAssignRoles(Request $request)
    {
       $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();

       $user->roles()->detach();
       if ($request['role_user'])
       {
           $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
       }

       if ($request['role_admin'])
       {
           $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first());
       }

       if ($request['role_superuser'])
       {
           $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Superuser')->first());
       }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

And my User class contains the following:

```php
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
       if (is_array($roles))
       {
           foreach ($roles as $role)
           {
               if ($this -> hasRole($role))
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if ($this -> hasRole($roles))
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

I also set up this in my middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null) 
        {
            return response("U bent niet bevoegd om deze actie uit te voeren.", 401);
        }
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;

        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response("U bent niet bevoegd om deze actie uit te voeren.", 401);
    }
```

and added this in the Kernel

```
'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class
```

I think the problem is that for one reason or another `$user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();` returns null. I tried `get()`instead of `first()`, but then I get a `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::roles does not exist.`error.

I'm sorry for the many code snippets, but I've been struggling with this for the past 8 hours and really don't know where to search the problem anymore. Please someone help me before I go cry myself to sleep in the corner of my room and never touch Laravel again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that calling `first()` on your query returns null, hence the reason why you get that error.

So what you can use to prevent calling `roles()` on null object is to use `firstOrFail()` method which will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` which you can catch using a `try` `catch` block and handle it gracefully.

And as I can see in your view you are not sending the value of the email in your form, so you should put the email in a hidden input:

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}" />
{{$user->email}}"
</td>
```

not having this is why you get `null` result.

Comment: Or `optional($user)->email` :)

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the values you are intending to pass are set, You can do so with isset
example @isset('$user->hasRole('User')');